# Why -webkit-slider-thumb:hover not works?

Tags: css, hover

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background: lime;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb,
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover,
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

Why hover not working? As I set background color yellow on hover it should do the task.

Comment: Do you want the slider background yellow only when hovering over the slider thumb or when hovering over anywhere on the slider? see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/j68w43hb/)

Comment: I want the slider thumb background yellow when hovering over the slider thumb only. You showed me the hovering over anywhere, I don't want it.

Answer (score 3):

Put separate css for firefox and try..

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background: lime;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: yellow;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

Comment: Yep, this works. For some reason, combining the selectors breaks things in Chrome as of March 2022.